# Will my iphone 3gs app work ok on iphone 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I'm currently making an app that supports both iphone 3gs and ipad (this is a universal binary app).

What I'm wondering is how will iphone 4 users view my app, will they see it pixelated? will they not see it full screen since my iphone 3gs is on a smaller resolution?

I don't have an iphone 4 yet but I'd rather just release this app as is - just for 3gs and ipad. Is there anything that I must know / any precautions etc? Oh (i just thought of this) is there an iphone 4.0 simulator so i can check out if my app works okay?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change your device type, by in the simulator pressing: Hardware->Device->iPhone 4  If you don't have it you might want download the latest devevloper tools.

Also you might have to press Window->Scale->100%

Comment: interestingly enough, my program looks exactly the same in both simulated devices. even the images look about the same (as far as pixelation goes). maybe the simulator has some bugs?.. hrmmmmm

Comment: Well you have to set it to the full view to see it at the actual resolution right now you are probably looking at it at standard resolution press Window->Scale->100%

Comment: hrmph.. the window/scale doesn't let me pick any options. (they are greyed out)

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Basically any bitmap graphics (PNG files) will look a little blurry on the iPhone 4's Retina display.

The easiest way to fix this is to make double scaled versions (100x100 becomes 200x200) of all your PNG files and add them to your project suffixed with "@2x.png".  In other words, MyBitmap.png will become MyBitmap@2x.png.  Luckily your code doesn't have to change.  On the iPhone 4 the OS will automatically choose a @2x.png instead of the regular one when you do:

```
UIImage *myBitmap = [UIImage imageNamed:@”MyBitmap.png”];
```

Xib files will also use the @2x.png if there is one available.

Other than that there's also launch images and Application Icons to worry about.  [This blog](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/6/29/updating-for-the-iphone-4-retinal-display.html) has a good summary.

Comment: okay, that's good to know. do you think the simulator should show this difference if i put those higher images in? i've not found the simulator to show much of a difference between between 3gs/4 so far.. i.e., it doesn't pixelate the images that are currently set to 3gs resolution...